# How do structure more than one for loop into an if statement?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to solve a problem with an array of numbers and 3 for loops in Java. It involves figuring out which 3 numbers from the array add up to a specific sum. For this test I used a sum of 9.

```
int nums[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15};

for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
        for (int y = 0; y <= 7; y++)

            if(nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[y] == 9)
                System.out.print(i + " " + j + " " + y);
}
```

The correct answer is 3 3 3 but this output reads:

```
0 0 30 1 20 2 10 3 01 0 21 1 11 2 02 0 12 1 03 0 0
```

I know I'm probably nesting the for loops completely wrong but I can't figure out where to put the code blocks without getting rid of one of the variables in the scope of the if statement. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't add a space at the end so the sets are `0 0 3` (1 + 1 + 7), `0 1 2` (1 + 3 + 5), etc. All add up to 9, so it is the correct output

Comment: The correct answer is definitely not 3 3 3, So if I am not wrong you want to find a triplet which sums up to your test sum, which in this case is 9, So correct answer is `1,3,5`

Comment: And yes, for starters: use println(), so that you got newlines between your different print statements. Helps with reading.

Comment: Make your System.out.print use `nums[i]`, not just `i`, etc

Comment: Are you intending to print the index or the actual numbers? You're printing indexes: ```j``` rather than ```num[j]``` for example.  Are you allowed repetition?  If not, then you need to cater for that in the for-loops.

Comment: Also:  I, j, y?  ;-)  'k' would seem to be a more obvious choice for the innermost loop variable.  Not that it changes the logic, but a reader of the existing code is apt to think "ok, why is 'y' used here?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your code

- You are printing the indexes `System.out.print(i + " " + j + " " + y);` instead you want to print the numbers.
- You want to use `println` to print everything on a newline
- You should not take a item from the  list multiple times, every inner loop should ignore elements already taken in account by outer loop
- 3,3,3 is not the answer since it contains repeated elements, the answer should be the one which contains distinct elements i.e. `1,3,5`

The updated code will then be

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j <= 7; j++)
        for (int y = j+1; y <= 7; y++)

            if( nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[y] == 9)
                //Print the numbers on newline
                System.out.println(nums[i] + " " +nums[j] + " " + nums[y]);
}
```

The output will be

```
1 3 5
```

If repetition is allowed, then all 3 loops will run from 0 and the answer changes

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
        for (int y = 0; y <= 7; y++)

            if( nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[y] == 9)
                //Print the numbers on newline
                System.out.println(nums[i] + " " +nums[j] + " " + nums[y]);
}
```

The answer will then be

```
1 1 7                                                                                                                                                          
1 3 5                                                                                                                                                          
1 5 3                                                                                                                                                          
1 7 1                                                                                                                                                          
3 1 5                                                                                                                                                          
3 3 3                                                                                                                                                          
3 5 1                                                                                                                                                          
5 1 3                                                                                                                                                          
5 3 1                                                                                                                                                          
7 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I should've mentioned that I intended for the numbers to be repeated but I guess 1, 3, 5 was the answer that I was actually looking for, and that first explanation worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

> The correct answer is 3 3 3 but this output reads:

No, The correct answer is definitely not `3 3 3`, So if I am not wrong you want to find a triplet which sums up to your test sum, which in this case is 9, So correct answer is 1,3,5
Try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j <= 7; j++)
   for (int y = j + 1; y <= 7; y++)

      if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[y] == 9)
       System.out.print(nums[i] + " " + nums[j] + " " + nums[y]);
}
```

Running Sample : https://ideone.com/5UAuGv

Comment: Thank you this answer works as well, and I didn't get what printing i j and y by themselves was doing at first and this makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 0):

You're testing the same values multiple times, i.e. 1+1+7, 1+7+1, 7+1+1 are all being tested. Use `for for (int j = i; j <= 7; j++)` and `for (int y = j; y <= 7; y++)`. Note that there are multiple answers, not just 3 3 3, **if you are allowing values to be used multiple times**.